# Kubernetes pod throttling

Tags: kubernetes

Let me try to explain our situation. At night we scale all deployments to 0 replicas (and store the original value in an annotation) to reduce costs.
In the morning the replicas are restored to their original values. This is where the problem starts as they overburden the node where the CPU plateaus to 100%.
The warmup probes start to fail and, if they make it, the liveness probes will start restaring the pods. Too many pods are trying to get up at the same time...
After about 2 hours the system finally stabilizes. If we startup the pods manually, say 5 per minute, the system comes up in less then 10 minutes (!).
In other domains this is called the thundering herd problem or stampede problem and we haven't found a fix yet for Kubernetes.

I understand that a project like Trimaran takes into account the CPU utilization but its goal is to be more efficient and not throttle pod creation per se right. Will we be abusing Trimaran for our use case or is it a good fit you think?

If not it is time for me to learn Go and the Scheduling Framework as it can't be too hard to install a throttle for pod creation on a node where x pods can be created in a sliding window of x minutes. Am I on the right track? Thank you.

This is the script that before the blackout stores the number of replicas in the annotations so that in the morning it can be restored to the original value:

```
# annotate first
kubectl get deploy -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"kubectl annotate --overwrite deploy "}{@.metadata.name}{" previous-size="}{@.spec.replicas}{" \n"}{end}' | sh

# scale to 0
kubectl scale --replicas=0 $(kubectl get deploy -o name)

# scaleback
kubectl get deploy -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"kubectl scale deploy "}{@.metadata.name}{" --replicas="}{.metadata.annotations.previous-size}{"\n"}{end}' | sh
```

**Update 1**
I investigated the resource request and limits but they state what in total can be run on a node. Not how it can throttle the number of pod creations per time window on the node.

Comment: Could you explain how you implemented the scale down/scale up currently in place?

Comment: used pod request and limit to use resource usage?

Comment: @HarshManvar Thanks but please see update 1

Comment: @Thomas I added the script that brings all replicas to 0 and restore them afterwards.

Comment: If the manual scale up solves your problem by slowing down, did you consider to scaling up in steps? You could even combine it with kubectl scale --timeout until the scale up is completed.

Comment: @buckley you can use kubernetes [cron jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) for scheduling pods. using this you can create different cron jobs for deploying each namesape in an orderly fashion with a time interval in order to prevent pod throttling.